# How can I create a decorator?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, decorator

I am writing a Web API client using TypeScript.
I wanted to use a decorator so that I could put a response briefly, but I do not know how to do it.

An example

```
class Client {
  private hasError(statusCode: number): ResponseError | null {
    let Err;
    // some...
    return Err
  }
  private response<T>(res: AxiosResponse): T | ResponseError {
    let err: ResponseError;
    if(err = this.hasError(res.status)) {
      return err;
    }
    return res.data as T
  }
  public async getSomeData(): Promise<SomeData | ResponseError> {
    return this.response<SomeData>(await axios.get("/api/endpoint"))
  }
}
```

I would like to write this response method with a decorator.

Thank you.